# Unable to load swagger api using docker container

Tags: docker, swagger

I am unable to load swagger api using Docker where as the jar file runs fine: `java -jar abc.jar`

My swagger api doc: `http://localhost:8080/api-docs/swagger.json`

Docker File

```
FROM openjdk:14.0.2
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY ./build/libs/OrderManagementSystem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/OrderManagementSystem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Command

```
docker run -p 3333:8080 order-price
```

I am unable to load the page `http://localhost:8080/swagger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your container like that:

```
docker run -p 3333:8080 order-price
```

You are telling docker to expose internal port 8080 to port 3333 on your host.
So if you wan't to access Swagger API, you have to use :

```
http://localhost:3333/swagger
```

If you really want to user port 8080 on your host, then you have to launch your container like that :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 order-price
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are **hitting the wrong URL**.

it should be,

```
http://localhost:3333/swagger
```

or

```
http://localhost:3333/api-docs/swagger.json
```

when you are binding ports while running docker,  it is `docker run -p host-port:container-port`

Comment: If my jar run separately loads with http://localhost:8080/swagger then I am not clear why I need to change to url to swagger-ui

Comment: @coder25 in that case you don't need to change to /swagger-ui and could you please share what's the error you are getting while calling http://localhost:3333/swagger ?

Comment: bc873136e7c4        orders              "java -jar /opt/app/…"   9 seconds ago       Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:3333->8080/tcp   wonderful_mclean

I am unable to load page